# jQuery mobile: URL query string does not change

Tags: url, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm playing around with jQuery Mobile and ran into some (for me) strange behavior.

I have a bunch of links each pointing to the same jQM page, `#otherpage`, but with different values for the URL query string, like `#otherpage?q=foo`, `#otherpage?q=bar`, and so on. The change to the other page works fine but the query string sticks between clicks, so if I first click the link to `#otherpage?q=foo`, and then goes back to the first page, all subsequent page changes to `#otherpage` will have `q=foo`, no matter what the currently clicked link's href says.

jsFiddle didn't seem to have support for jQM so I put an example here: http://cpak.se/dump/location-search-test.html

I've tried this in Chrome and Safari on Mac.

I use the query string to pass simple data between pages since I have other code hooked into the pagechange events, that is more or less unaware of what earlier code might have done. If I can't get this working I'll have to find another way to pass data around... :P

Cheers!

/Christofer

Comment: I know this is an old issue but if you're still having issues, I recently created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which might help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked up for this issue because it seems a little bit weird indeed. There is a open issue about this: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2859

Atm jQuery Mobile doesn't recommend using query parameters:

> We don't currently support query parameters as part of the hash
>   fragment, though this is something that's been discussed frequently
>   internally and is on the feature request list.

They advise to use a plugin like:

- https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params
- https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router

However, there is a workaround since the data-url of the active page in the DOM DOES change, you can retrieve this with `$(".ui-page-active").attr("data-url");` I've tested this on your website and it gave me all 3 uniques URLs

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to dig that out for me! I'll give "data-url" a try.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling jQm seems to be the easiest solution for updating the url parameters correctly in the browser. E.g. adding `data-ajax="false"` in the link anchor and not using `$.mobile.changePage`.

```
<a href="#page?id=1" data-ajax="false">
```

In a dynamic app modify the value of href beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile by default does not allow passing query-string parameters to internally linked pages. Check-out the very bottom of this documentation page (the second bullet from the bottom of the page): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

> jQuery Mobile does not support query parameter passing to
>   internal/embedded pages but there are two plugins that you can add to
>   your project to support this feature. There is a lightweight [page
>   params plugin](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params) and a more fully featured [jQuery Mobile router
>   plugin](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router) for use with backbone.js or spine.js.