# jQuery mobile : Linking next page doesn't work on Windows phone using phonegap

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

Currently im building a application using phonegap & jQuery Mobile

I have done the version which is perfectly working on iOS & Android.But the same code does not work on windows phone.When i click any link,redirection to the respective page is not loading..Its still says "Error Page loading".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Test

```
<div  id="bg">
    <div style="padding-top:14%;width:100%;text-align:center">
        <div style="float:left;text-align:center;width:50%"><a href="list.html?qs=1"><img src="pics/btn_1.png" /></a></div>
        <div style="float:left;text-align:center;width:50%"><a href="list.html?qs=2"><img src="pics/btn_2.png" /></a></div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

Need help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

Add `data-ajax=false` or `rel=external` to your `anchor` tag. But, if you do this, you will lose transitions. This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax hash in the URL. You could enable this if the incoming device is a windows phone if needed :

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    //check for windows phone
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

Else, make your code into a single page template. Here's a demo of that : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/aYW2f/

#### Edit

Currently [jQM doesn't support query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129637/jquery-mobile-url-query-string-does-not-change). You could use the `localStorage` API to store the parameters in cache and retrieve them later. Assuming you want to go to `index.html` from here :

```
<a href="list.html?qs=2" rel="external"><img src="pics/btn_2.png" /></a>
```

You'd add a click event for it :

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
  //gets qs=2 and changes it into ["qs",2]
  var query = this.href.split["?"][2].split["="];
  //construct an array out of that
  var paramString = { query[0]: query[1]} ;
  //store it in localstorage
  locaStorage["query"] = JSON.stringify(paramString);
  //continue redirection
  return true;
});
```

In your `index.html` :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "[data-role=page]", function() {
      //store it in localstorage
      var params = JSON.parse(locaStorage["query"]);
      //now params will contain { "qs" : 2 }
      //you could access "2" by params["qs"]
});
```

[More info about `localStorage` here.](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: Thanks..how to make a single page template?It would be great if you share any reference link

Comment: :) nice..if you think this answer will help future visitors pls upvote it :)

Comment: Sure..I have updated the code.Pls look that.I need to pass the query string value in order to display the separate content based on the query string values.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had Also same issue and finally resolve it by using below code

my html page is index.html and i am writtinga all code in one html

Before

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#second", {});
```

After

```
var url = window.location.href;
       url = url.split('#').pop().split('?').pop();
       url = url.replace(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),"index.html#second");
     $.mobile.changePage(url, { reloadPage : false, changeHash : false });
```

and suppose you have multiple html page then for more one page to another you can use

```
var url = window.location.href;
       url = url.split('#').pop().split('?').pop();
       url = url.replace(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),"second.html");
     $.mobile.changePage(url, { reloadPage : false, changeHash : false });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support of querystring in web application using phonegap for windows phone 7.

However we can replace ? with # or anything else to pass the data,

like convert

```
Sample.html?id=12312
```

to

```
Sample.html#id=12312
```